# Как в JQuery сделать появление кнопки по нескольким чекбоксам?

Tags: jquery

Есть 3 чекбокса. Когда 1 из 3 выбран или 2 или 3 то должна появится кнопка. Если снять все 3 чекбокса, то кнопка должна исчезнуть.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="first" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="second" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="third" class="checkbox">
    <button class="hidden" id="btn">Я кнопка</button>

    <script>
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {
        var check = false;
        $('.checkbox').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
              check = true;
            }
        });
        if(check) {
            $('#btn').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#btn').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
    </script>

    <style>
        .hidden {display: none;}
    </style>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у мня почему то не работает. кнопка видно и не исчезает тоже.

Comment: Добавьте свойства css для класса hidden
`.hidden {display: none;}` - например

Comment: Или используйте вместо `removeClass()` - `show()`, а вместо `addClass()` - `hide()`. И первоначально скройте кнопку `style="display:none;"`

Comment: Спасибо получилось с show и hide. Почему removeClass и addClass не работали у меня ?  И почему с <input type="submit" id="btn"> не работает ? а только с <button id="btn">

Comment: removeClass и addClass не работали, потому что у Вас не существовало класса hidden в стилях CSS. с <input type="submit" id="btn"> должно работать. ищите ошибку где то глубже

Comment: помогло когда сделал input класс btn и переделал скрипт под .btn вместо #btn. Спасибо большое

Answer (score -1):

```
function(){     
    if($("#id_checkbox").attr("checked") == 'checked') {
        $("#id_button").show();
    } else {
        $("#id_button").hide();
    }
}
```